# How To Load Multiple PFFiles from Parse in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I am using Parse for an iOS app and it requires me to load multiple image in one PFObject, and so I have multiple PFFiles in that object. I know you have to load each object seperately in order to use it, but is there a way to load multiple PFFiles at once from an object? Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you retrieve a PFObject, you don't actually pull down any PFFiles pointed to within that object anyway, you always need to manually pull down the file, whether it is 1 file or 5 files.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ManyFileClass"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"OBJECT_ID" 
                             block:^(PFObject *manyFileClass, NSError *error) {
    PFFile* file1 = [o objectForKey:@"file1"];
    PFFile* file2 = [o objectForKey:@"file2"];

    [data1 getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Got data from file1@");
        }
    }];

    [data2 getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Got data from file2@");
        }
    }];

}];
```

Comment: this still actually sends 2 queries to pull 2 files right? is there a way to only to this with one query? cause you know parse has a limit on query counts

Comment: Correct, this is 2 queries. From a non-technical point of view When I developed an app I spent a massive amount of time trying to minimise my parse query count. In the end the query count is pretty decent, and looking back, the time would have been better spent attracting more users or implementing additional features.

Comment: Also keep in mind, all files stored in Parse have a public URL, so you can just download them using non-parse methods, and this won't have any impact on your API call limit.

Answer (score 2):

for other new folks like me, i believe the accepted answer from 'ahar083' may have a typo in it.  i changed 'data1' to 'file1' and 'data2' to 'file2' (updated code  = pasted below).  i do not have enough points to comment on an answer = posted my comment as a new answer.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ManyFileClass"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"OBJECT_ID" 
                             block:^(PFObject *manyFileClass, NSError *error) {
    PFFile* file1 = [o objectForKey:@"file1"];
    PFFile* file2 = [o objectForKey:@"file2"];

    [file1 getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Got data from file1@");
        }
    }];

    [file2 getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Got data from file2@");
        }
    }];

}];
```

Comment: this still actually sends 2 queries to pull 2 files right? is there a way to only to this with one query? cause you know parse has a limit on query counts

Comment: @Esq i have not found way to pull 2 files with 1 query.